# Highcharts: One Legend Controls Many Charts

Tags: highcharts

I have a number of metrics (e.g. Housing, Population, Income) for a number of towns that I have split into separate charts - one chart for Housing, one for Population ect. I would like to use one legend to control the visible series for each of the charts - is this possible? I.e If one series visibility is toggled on the legend, that series should be removed from all charts.

This JS Fiddle illustrates this further:

http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/fak50quv/1/

```
$(function () {
```

Comment: In the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730755/two-pies-one-legend-with-unique-items-merge-legends/16737076#16737076 I introduced how to create common legend. Second solution is catch the legendItemClick action, like in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the legend items, a legendItemClick event happens.  You can define a handler for that in the plotOptions.
The following code has no error checking, etc.  But, it should get you started.
http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/fak50quv/2/

```
         plotOptions: {
            series: {
                events: {
                    legendItemClick: function () {
                        var visibility = this.visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden';
                        var series = $('#PeopleChart').highcharts().series[this.index];
                        if (this.visible) series.hide();
                        else series.show();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```